# Listen to probe requests from wi-fi devices

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have an android device which is configured as a wireless hotspot. I want to find out how I can listen to "Probe Requests" from devices using Android APIs.

I know this can be done by using various tools but only when you have root access. I believe we should also be able to listen to Probe Requests without the root access. This is because, when we set the phone in hotspot mode it is able to connect to other devices without being in root mode. In order to make a connection, the hotspot device must be processing Probe Requests that it receives from other devices.

I have tried looking in /proc/arp/net file but it only shows information about devices which are connected to the hotspot.

If it's not possible without the root access then I would like to know how an hotspot enabled device is able to accept connections without being in root mode?

Comment: "how an hotspot enabled device is able to accept connections without being in root mode?" - Besides the "apps" there are of course native, system-level drivers and processes working in the background, which naturally have full access to the OS and hardware. There is no need to expose raw driver APIs to any non-root user because the system itself handles things like e.g. networking.

Comment: oh yes forgot about permissions stuff thanks. So, such things are not possible until you have root access then?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe look at http://blog.linuxconsulting.ro/2010/04/porting-wifi-drivers-to-android.html, or the API of `wpa_supplicant` in general. Then maybe find out how e.g. [pingSupplicant()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#pingSupplicant%28%29) is implemented; you may be able to build something based upon that to communicate with the lower layers of the network stack.

Comment: http://jhshi.me/2014/04/25/how-android-wifi-state-machine-works/ looks interesting too.