# Listen to probe requests from Wifi devices on [rooted] Android

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, rooted-device

I know that we can not listen to probe requests on non-rooted Android because of permission issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968480/listen-to-probe-requests-from-wi-fi-devices).

I have successfully obtained the probe requests on my Linux machine and studied [this](http://bcmon.blogspot.com/2012/09/working-monitor-mode-on-nexus-one.html) method but it only allow after patching the firmware of network cards and it is too old. Now, I have checked the Android API's, they do allow Wifi Hotspot mode, but they don't return probe requests, just only the devices with whom we are connected.

Can somebody point me in the right direction to obtain probe requests within rooted phone?